# Hide the content before the more tag in the "single page"

Tags: php, functions

On my homepage I want to display the content before the More tag (`<!--more-->`), but when I go to the single page, I want to hide all the content before the More tag and display the rest of the post.

Is it possible to do this ? (I don't want un the Excerpt due to some limitations for me (images, shortcodes, ...)).

Thank you :)

Comment: have you considered asking how to apply shortcodes and images to post excerpts instead?

Answer (score -1):

I anwser myself: `<?php the_content('readmore', true); ?>`